# (WSGI - Apache2/Flask) ImportError: cannot import name app

Tags: python, flask, import, mod-wsgi, wsgi

can someone help me. I tried everything out. Renaming, moving files and nothing changes. Im using WSGI Apache to run my Flask Application on localhost:80.

[Here is my File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juDnc.png)

My flask.wsgi File

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/flask_project/")

from flask_project import app as application
```

My **init**.py File

```
#! /bin/usr/python
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    return "Hi there, how ya doin?"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

My flaskapp.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAdmin youemail@email.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/flask_project/flask.wsgi

    <Directory /var/www/flask_project/flask_project/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    Alias /static /var/www/flask_project/flask_project/static
    <Directory /var/www/flask_project/flask_project/static/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Would be nice if someone knows what the issue is. Thanks in advance

Comment: post the complete error traceback please

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Zjio1fC.png

Comment: Your code under Apache will run as the Apache user. Are you sure your directories/files are readable to others, or do they have more restrictive permissions.

Comment: chmoded it temporary 777 , cuz its internal

Comment: Have you tried to rule out SELinux, by setting it to permissive (`#setenforce 0`) ? It is enabled by default on EC2 RHEL and will prevent WSGI scripts from importing some custom libraries, like needed for your Flask app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st Check Your Path**

From my understanding of your apache2 config and wsgi your path is:

`/var/www/flask_project/flask_project/application`

Although I think you are missing the `html` directory:

`/var/www/html/flask_project/flask_project/application`

**2nd Check If WSGI is enabled**

However, if that truly is your path then it may be likely that you didn't enable the WSGI after installation.

Try:

- `sudo a2enmod wsgi`
- `sudo service apache2 restart`

**Do you need virtualenv?**

Additionally, are you using virtualenv (venv) within your flask application? If so you will need to activate it inside of your WSGI.

Example:

```
activate_this=/var/www/html/flask_project/flask_project/benv/bin/activate_this.py
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
```

Comment: That is not the recommended way of setting up the virtual environment for mod_wsgi. Read http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html